# converting an Objective-C block variable to a Swift closure variable?

Tags: swift

I have an Objective-C block variable that I'd like to convert to Swift, but have been unsuccessful so far:

```
void(^stopBackBackgroundTaskBlock)()
```

An example of its use:

```
stopBackBackgroundTaskBlock = [^
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskId];
            backgroundTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    } copy];
```

How can I convert this code to Swift?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Question and Answer site, not a code translation service. Try to translate the code yourself first, then come to us when you are stuck, making sure to show us [what you have tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var stopBackBackgroundTaskBlock:()->() = {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(backgroundTaskId)
    backgroundTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
}
```

When you want to execute this block

```
stopBackBackgroundTaskBlock()
```

Comment: It might be helpful to the OP to explain why one version has `copy` but the other doesn't.